# Regex for substring of comma separated list

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm a beginner to regex, so I apologize in advance if this is a naive question!

I have a string with two values separated by a comma: `12.345678,23.45678901`

I am trying to use regex (this is a requirement) to return the first value with 3 decimals `12.345` and the second value with 2 decimals `23.45`.

Ideally, the full regex match would be `12.345,23.45`

I am able to get the first value 12.345 using the following regex: `^\d+\.\d{0,3}`.

This works well because it only returns the full match (there is no Group 1 match). But I'm pretty stumped on how to get the second value 23.45 to be returned in the same string.

I've also tried this regex: 
`(^.{0,6})(?:.*)(,)(.{0,5})`, which correctly parses the first and second values, but the full match is being returned with too many decimals.

Full match: `12.345678,23.45`

Group 1: `12.345`

Group 2: `,`

Group 3: `23.45`

Any suggestions are welcome! Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you try to explode()?

Comment: As Hemant mentions, splitting the string by `,` and then outputting data based on your format will result in readable and maintainable code, I feel.

Comment: Can't explode() unfortunately. I can add regex as a configuration, but I can't update the php code itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex to get your data:

```
^(\d+\.\d{3})\d*,(\d+\.\d{2})\d*$
```

It looks for digits followed by `.` and 3 decimal places (first capture group), then some number of digits followed by a comma (discarded) and then digits followed by a `.` and 2 decimal places (second capture group), followed finally by some number of digits and the end of string (discarded).

To use in PHP

```
$str = '12.345678,23.45678901';
preg_match('/^(\d+\.\d{3})\d*,(\d+\.\d{2})\d*$/', $str, $matches);
echo "first number: {$matches[1]}\nsecond number: {$matches[2]}\n";
```

Output:

```
first number: 12.345 
second number: 23.45
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/n9s5O)

If you need to get both matches in the `$matches[0]` array (using `preg_match_all`), you can use this regex:

```
(?<=^)\d+\.\d{3}(?=\d*,)|(?<=,)\d+\.\d{2}(?=\d*$)
```

This regex looks for either

- the start of string followed by some digits, a `.` and 3 digits (followed by some number of digits and a comma); or
- a comma, some number of digits, a `.` and 2 digits (followed by some number of digits and the end of string).

To avoid capturing the unwanted data it is checked for using positive lookaheads and lookbehinds.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/TVSC6)

Comment: Really appreciate the quick and helpful response! Is there a way to update that Regex to do the same thing, but in a string with superfluous brackets and/or quotes? That is, if the original string is instead [["12.345678,23.45678901"]] and I want the output to be 12.345 and 23.45?

Comment: @mazziestar you can make it work by removing the start and end of string anchors. See this updated demo https://3v4l.org/QMdKR